# Errors displaying an image uploaded into pictures folder in my root folder

Tags: php, mysql, image

Please I need your help with my script. I have a page where i upload user informations with there signature into a signatures folder in the root folder using
this section of my code below:

```
                {
                $uploaddir = "uploads";

                $file = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES
  ['signature']['name']);       

       switch($_FILES['signature']['type']) {
                case "image/gif":                        
                case "image/jpeg":
                case "image/pjpeg":
                case "image/png":
                $uploaddir .= 'signatures';
                break;                                                                                    

                }         

                foreach($_FILES as $signature)                                             

   $tmp_name = $signature['tmp_name'];
                $type = $signature['type'];
                $name = $signature['name'];
                $size = $signature['size'];      


                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES
   ['signature']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.        $file)) {

         $query = "INSERT INTO users                  (users_id, tmp_name, type, name, size)  
       VALUES (NULL,  '$tmp_name', '$type'          , '$name' , '$size')"
     mysql_query($query) or
     die (mysql_error()); 
                }
```

This is the query i'm using to call the name of the file i want.

```
 $query10 = mysql_query("SELECT name 
                      FROM  users
             WHERE username = '".$_SESSION        ['logged_username']."'") or 
   die (mysql_error());  
               $signature = mysql_fetch_array        ($query10);
```

How i'm trying to show the signature i uploaded with a php script.

```
 echo "<img  src = \"uploads\""?><?php                   echo $signature['name'] ;?>"/<?        php "width=\"50\" height=\"100\">" ;
```

The picture is not showing, although it showed a small box with nothing inside it. I'm quite sure the picture was uploaded into the signature folder of my root.

Please forgive my formatting. I meant no disprespect to this community.
I'll be most delighted with your comments, answers and suggestions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: check with view source ? what src path you are getting in img tag

Comment: have you checked your code for upload is working fine?

Comment: This is what i'm getting....

<img src = "uploads"signature.png"/>

Comment: ok check my answer and do as directed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $uploadpath="uploads/signatures/";
             echo "<img  src =".$uploadpath.      $signature['name']." width=\"50\"               height = \"100"\>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace code for displaying image with below:

```
  $uploadpath="uploads/";
  echo "<img  src ='".$uploadpath.$signature['name']."' width='50' height='100'>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the most obvious reason seems to be that you are reading the images from a different path than where you are storing them. As you have mentioned, you are saving images in the "signatures" folder but you are reading from "uploads" folder instead. Try this echo:

```
echo '<img  src = "signatures"' . $signature['name'] . ' width="50" height="100">';
```

If the above still doesn't show the image, it needs some debugging.

1. In the PHP code, there are 2 likely destinations for storing images - "uploads" and "signatures" folders. Please ensure into which folder are the images saving. Perhaps you should first check in which path does the image exists (using file_exists) and then accordingly decide which path to use as source.
2. Please ensure that the images are actually uploading

By the way, is there a specific reason for escaping the \ (back-slash) in your PHP code:

```
$uploaddir = "uploads\\";
$uploaddir = "signatures\\";
```

Hope above helps!

Comment: I will suggest using absolute paths when working with image sources to avoid any path issues